# Problem with DropDownlist in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating dropdown(country,state and city in table in mvc, but not inserted countryname,statename,cityname and country wise state not bind the proper data all the state and city display in dropdownlist?)

ex:
When I Select Russia then all the state of usa and russia display in dropdownlist??   //see the referance

I m applying code first approach in asp.net core mvc

Manager.cs

```cs
    public class Manager
    {
        [Key]
        public int ManagerId { get; set; }
        public string ManagerName { get; set; }

        //Insertion in Manager table country state and city
        [ForeignKey("country")]
        public int countryId { get; set; }
        public string countryname { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("state")]
        public int stateId { get; set; }
        public string statename { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("city")]
        public int cityId { get; set; }
        public string cityname { get; set; }

    }

    public class city
    {
        public int cityId { get; set; }
        public string cityname { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("state")]
        public int stateId { get; set; }
        public virtual state states { get; set; }
    }

    public class state
    {
        public int stateId { get; set; }
        public string statename { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("country")]
        public int countryId { get; set; }
        public virtual country countrys { get; set; }
    }

    public class country
    {
        public int countryId { get; set; }
        public string countryname { get; set; }
    }
```

dbcontext.cs

```cs
    public class dbcontext : IdentityDbContext<Student>
    {
        public dbcontext(DbContextOptions<dbcontext> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Manager> manages {get;set;}
        public virtual DbSet<country> countrys { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<state> states { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<city> citys { get; set; }

    }
```

HomeController:

```cs
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly dbcontext contxtclass;

        public HomeController(dbcontext contxtclass)
        {
            this.contxtclass = contxtclass;
        }

        //not inserted countryname,stataname and cityname in database see the Referance image


        [HttpGet]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id)
        {
            var manager = await contxtclass.manages
                        .Include(m => m.countryname)
                        .Include(m => m.statename)
                        .Include(m => m.cityname)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ManagerId == id);
            var countryname = manager.countryname;
            return View(manager);
        }//here i m put debugger then get an error object referance not set to an object

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ManagerId,ManagerName,countryId,countryname,stateId,statename,cityId,cityname")] Manager manager)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                manager.countryname=(await contxtclass.countrys.FindAsync(manager.countryId)).countryname;
                manager.cityname = (await contxtclass.states.FindAsync(manager.stateId)).statename;
                manager.statename = (await contxtclass.citys.FindAsync(manager.cityId)).cityname;
                contxtclass.Add(manager);
                await contxtclass.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            //bound the country table record
            List<country> countrylist = new List<country>();
            countrylist = (from countrys in contxtclass.countrys select countrys).ToList();
            countrylist.Insert(0, new country { countryname = "Select" });
            ViewBag.listofcountry = countrylist;

            //bound the state table record
            List<state> statelist = new List<state>();
            statelist = (from states in contxtclass.states select states).ToList();
            statelist.Insert(0, new state { statename = "Select" });
            ViewBag.listofstate = statelist;

            //bound the city table record
            List<city> citylist = new List<city>();
            citylist = (from citys in contxtclass.citys select citys).ToList();
            citylist.Insert(0, new city { cityname = "Select" });
            ViewBag.listofcity = citylist;

            return View(manager);
        }
```

create.cshtml

```cs
@model WebApplication2.Models.Manager

@{
    Layout = null;
}  
<h2>Create</h2>
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
            <div>
                <label asp-for="ManagerName"></label>
                <input asp-for="ManagerName"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="ManagerName"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                <div>
                    <label asp-for="countryname"></label>
                    <select asp-for="countryId"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.listofcountry,"countryId","countryname"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                <div>
                    <label asp-for="statename"></label>
                    <select asp-for="stateId"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.listofstate,"stateId","statename"))"></select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="alert-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                <div>
                    <label asp-for="cityname"></label>
                    <select asp-for="cityId"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.listofcity,"cityId","cityname"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

this code place in httpget(create) method???i put this code in httpget method

```
var manager = await _context.manages
            .Include(m => m.country)
            .Include(m => m.state)
            .Include(m => m.city)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ManagerId == id);
var countryname = mamager.country.countryname;
```

give an error object referance not set to an object???

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJMOv.jpg

Comment: From an experienced programmer to you: Posting a huge code snippet of database, controller, view for help is not normal. If I answer your immediate question it will not help you. You need to learn how to properly troubleshoot. I'm going to tell you how. Simplify your problem by commenting out your other lists in the controller and then use your debugger to make sure you're getting what you expect back from the database and find out where the problem is so you can investigate that area. If you are getting data back from the database then your problem might be in the view.

Comment: Also, `ViewBag` is really just a construct for providing data to a master page from your view. You shouldn't be using `ViewBag` in your views, but a strongly typed Model.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan when I m debugging my code then  ```c# create.cshtml  @model WebApplication2.Models.Manager

@{
    Layout = null;
}```//here stop my debugger and give an error Value cannot be null. means my debugger not check the whole content  ```<Html><body></html></body>``` in create.cshtml code

Comment: @Nicosdench added an answer and explanation

Comment: @TheMuffinMan i edit mycreate.cshtml see this ??

Comment: @TheMuffinMan stll my countryname,statename,cityname not inserted in database? viewbag is a dynamic property  which change in my code and then record inserted in database??how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, when I add a breakpoint on `POST` action, the `countryname`,`cityname`,`statename` are all null since you do not pass that to action.

Your dropdownlist `<select asp-for="countryId">` passes countryId only.

To quickly get the result, you could retrieve the name by their own Id, and set the `ViewBag` again to prevent error of `value can not be null` when the model state is invalid.

Modified code is written as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ManagerId,ManagerName,countryId,countryname,stateId,statename,cityId,cityname")] Manager manager)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            manager.countryname = (await _context.countrys.FindAsync(manager.countryId)).countryname;
            manager.statename = (await _context.states.FindAsync(manager.stateId)).statename;
            manager.cityname = (await _context.citys.FindAsync(manager.cityId)).cityname;
            _context.Add(manager);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }


        //To prevent your error, you need to set `ViewBag` again

        List<country> countrylist = new List<country>();
        countrylist = (from countrys in contxtclass.countrys select countrys).ToList();
        countrylist.Insert(0,new country {  countryname = "Select" });
        ViewBag.listofcountry = countrylist;

        //bound the state table record
        List<state> statelist = new List<state>();
        statelist = (from states in contxtclass.states select states).ToList();
        statelist.Insert(0, new state { statename = "Select" });
        ViewBag.listofstate = statelist;

        //bound the city table record
        List<city> citylist = new List<city>();
        citylist = (from citys in contxtclass.citys select citys).ToList();
        citylist.Insert(0, new city { cityname = "Select" });
        ViewBag.listofcity = citylist;

        return View(manager);
    }
```

Another recommended way is that you could just add relationships between your manager and country/state/city model like:

```
public class Manager
{
    [Key]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("country")]
    public int countryId { get; set; }
    public country country { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("state")]
    public int stateId { get; set; }
    public state state { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("city")]
    public int cityId { get; set; }
    public city city { get; set; }

}
```

Then you only need to save the three foreign keys to manager table and get the name by

```
var manager = await _context.manages
            .Include(m => m.country)
            .Include(m => m.state)
            .Include(m => m.city)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ManagerId == id);
var countryname = mamager.country.countryname;
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading

Update:

`Get` method:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        //bound the country table record
        List<country> countrylist = new List<country>();
        countrylist = (from countrys in _context.countrys select countrys).ToList();
        countrylist.Insert(0, new country { countryname = "Select" });
        ViewBag.listofcountry = countrylist;

        //bound the state table record
        List<state> statelist = new List<state>();
        statelist = (from states in _context.states select states).ToList();
        statelist.Insert(0, new state { statename = "Select" });
        ViewBag.listofstate = statelist;

        //bound the city table record
        List<city> citylist = new List<city>();
        citylist = (from citys in _context.citys select citys).ToList();
        citylist.Insert(0, new city { cityname = "Select" });
        ViewBag.listofcity = citylist;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I edit my question  ```var manager = await _context.manages
            .Include(m => m.country)
            .Include(m => m.state)
            .Include(m => m.city)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ManagerId == id);
var countryname = mamager.country.countryname;``` this code where can i put ?? still some issue

Comment: @Nicos dench That code is only an example ,it is used in Index action or anywhere you need it.With that, you could show the countryname in Index view with something like `@item.country.countryname`

Comment: but this code is necessary to implement in my current code situation?

Comment: @Nicos dench No,it is not necessary to use include for just saving data.You do not need to modify you create `GET` method and I do not use `countryname` in model, instead with a navigation propertity `country`.It seems that you do not modify that.

Comment: @Nicos dench The second way will not retrieve countryname directly from manager table but with a navigation property, and get by `manager.country.countryname`, that is why I use above code.Besides,does the first solution work?

Comment: Thanks for your susggestion but still get an error Value cannot be null.

Comment: @Nicos dench It works well when I test.Do you add a breakpoint to see whether model state is valid?Is that error in create view?

Comment: when I put the break point ```[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
           //when i run my code and here i put the debugger then give an error value can not be null
            return View();
        }
```  I get this error value can not be null and i also updated my create.cshtml view i m trying and trying but my error not solve

Comment: @Nicos dench Your `ViewBag`s need to be set both in `GET` or `POST` of `create`  method,I see that you have remove that in `GET`...As I said, your create `GET` mehod is correct before.You always need to pass those viewbags when you return the create view

Comment: i put this code in get method still get an error object referance not set to an object??

Comment: @Nicos dench See my update...I mean those ViewBags for dropdownlist.Besides, do you save correct data into database already?

Comment: thanks for your large suggestion very helpful i m trying and trying again trying and trying again trying and trying, now i realized my data is ready for the save but where to save means get method give an error object referance not set to an object.

Answer (score 0):

in your `create.cshtml` your view is expecting a model `WebApplication2.Models.Manager`

but in your `return View();` in your `Create()` you are not passing anything.

you can fix this error by generating
first if you just need an empty model

```
return View(new //WebApplication2.Models.Manager class);
```

or retrieve something from your context (based on the name it is only one manager)

```
return View(context.Managers.First(x => condition)));
```